# How could I determine the value of a a 1921 Yuan Shikai Chinese silver dollar?

Tags: china, currency

I have a 1921 Yuan Shikai Chinese silver dollar. What is the history of this coin, and how could I determine the worth/value of my coin?

Comment: depending on how good of shape the coin is in it can go for anything between 40-250 USD.

Comment: You can determine value the same way you determine value for anything without a fixed price tag, whether that's art, real estate, stock, or collectibles - see how much someone will pay you for it.

Comment: I'll give you 99 Yuan Shikari cents for it

Comment: also if you literally google "Yuan Shikai Silver Coin" you will find several pages that give full histories of the coin and the various mints and years it was run.  After further research most of the coins are very common,  but there are some valuable rare ones out there too,  so i would try to upload a picture.

Answer (score 1):

> Question:
>   How could I determine the value of a a 1921 Yuan Shikai Chinese silver dollar?

I assume you are speaking of the numismatic value?  because if you are not the answer is you weigh the coin and check the value of silver per ounce.  Which is often the right answer to this question.

Alternatively you can check ebay and see what other folks are asking..   and that answer is between $4.75 - $1,249.99 cents.  Here is the **[search](https://www.ebay.com/b/Silver-1921-Year-Chinese-Coins/40712/bn_113392965)** I did..   depending upon condition.   That's what a numismatics might call a wide spread.

I think many precious metal coins value is tied to the price of the metal.   I know gold and silver coins in the United States are not worth more than the cost of the cold or silver.  This is because back in the 19th and early 20th centuries it was common practice for the countries(including the US) to pay international debts with bulk transfers of un-circulated coins.   So one can still go to a coin show and pay a premium for American coins, or you can go to gold re-sellers and purchase circulated american gold coins for the price of the gold.   Europe has hundreds of thousands of uncirculated gold coins anybody can purchase for the price of the gold.  So I would probable

> **[The Numismatic News: The 1908 No Motto Double Eagle](https://www.numismaticnews.net/article/features/the-1908-no-motto-double-eagle)**
>   Under the circumstances, there was basically no saving of the 1908 No Motto Saint-Gaudens double eagle. The mintage was assumed to have reached circulation. A significant number were simply placed in vaults and in many cases sent to European banks or banks in other nations.
>
> When American dealers later went and purchased the coins which had been in foreign banks for decades, the best examples were in lower Mint State grades. The Wells Fargo Hoard of 19,900 examples of the No Motto 1908 Saint-Gaudens double eagle was an exception. Found in the 1990s and purchased by dealer Ron Gillio, the hoard was simply exceptional.
>
> In MS-65 the 1908 without a motto lists for $1,545 because it’s the Wells Fargo Hoard, which had the best grades seen in such hoards and in large numbers.